# Reverting a commit only a specific branch, while keeping the "merged data"

Tags: git, git-revert

Say I have two branches `A` and `master`. A feature has accidentally been added, and completed, to branch `A` (which is also working on a different feature that is in a working state/merged to master but needs to be continued on later).

Now I wish to remove the commit(s) that produced the new feature from `A` while keeping the master state in the current HEAD. Ideally something like:

```
git checkout A
git revert HEAD~2..HEAD
```

However wouldn't this also revert the HEAD of master branch?

Comment: First of all, don't ask us what would happen. Tell us what you want to happen. The way I understood your question is that you have a branch, A, where you have (accidentally) added something unrelated, then you merged A to master. Now, you want to revert/undo/remove that unrelated thing from A, but you want to keep it on master. Did I understand that right?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen - Yes but more importantly I wish to understand how "things like revert" work with branches. Do they work on a single branch or do they also revert other branches.

Comment: A revert just adds another commit that does the reverse of the commit you're reverting. If the original commit added a line, the revert commit removes it, and so on. A revert adds another commit, you need to merge that commit into the relevant branches yourself. Revert cannot insert a commit into the history, nor change the original commit, so it affects the branches you want it to affect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution with rewriting history:

```
git checkout A
git reset HEAD~2
git push origin A --force
```

An important thing is that after `git reset` command all your changes from the two latest commits will be available in the working directory. It gives you an opportunity to create another branch and continue working on it or stash if needed.

### Solution without rewriting history:

```
git checkout A
# automatically commits
git revert HEAD~2..HEAD
git push origin A
```

or

```
git checkout A

# doesn't commit automatically 
git revert --no-commit HEAD~2..HEAD

git commit -m 'Revert two last commits'
git push origin A
```

It will add a new commit to reverse the effect of two latest commits.

#### All the above solutions doesn't change `master` branch!

### Theory:

`HEAD` is the pointer to the current branch reference, which is in turn a pointer to the last commit made on that branch.

What does `git checkout [<branch>]` really do?

- changes `HEAD` to point the new branch ref
- populates your `index` (staging area) with the snapshot of that commit
- copies the contents of the `index` into your working directory

What does `git reset [<commit>]` really do?

- moves the branch that `HEAD` is pointing to (Suppose you're currently on the `master` branch. Running `git reset [<commit>]` will make `master` point to `[<commit>]`)
- update the `index` (staging area) with the contents of snapshot `HEAD` points to

Answer (score 2):

`HEAD` is a pointer to the current active branch.

After running `git checkout A`, acting on `HEAD` will modify `A` and not `master`,
after running `git checkout master`, acting on `HEAD` will modify `master` and not `A`.

---

an extra note :

If your intention is to "cancel the last two commits from branch `A`", you can run :

```
git checkout A
git reset --hard HEAD~2

# if branch A was pushed,
# you will also need to push the corrected A :
git push origin --force-with-lease A
```

Comment: I have indeed pushed A (and master) - can I do the revert without rewriting history?

Comment: Is one of the two reverted commits a merge commit from `master` into `A` ?

Comment: Things will be simpler if you can run the `reset --hard`, which does rewrite the history. If this goes against a hard requirement, you can run the `revert` command, but double check what will land in `master` later on, when `A` gets merged into `master`.